# Coordinate-free proof of the hamiltonian character of the geodesic flow

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let be $(M,g)$ a pseudoriemannian manifold.  Let us identify the tangent and the cotangent bundles through the musical isomorphism $g^\flat:u\in TM\to g(u,\cdot)\in T^\ast M.$

It is well known that:

> The geodesics of $(M,g),$ i.e. the solutions of
>   $\frac{D}{dt}\gamma=0,$ are integral curves for the hamiltonian vector
>   field of $K:u\in TM\to \tfrac{1}{2}g(u,u)\in\mathbb{R}$ w.r.t. the
>   canonical symplectic form.

**Question** Knowing how to show it using coordinates, I am wondering how to prove it in an intrinsic way.

Comment: I have posted it even on MO, here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88624/is-there-a-coordinate-free-proof-of-the-hamiltonian-character-of-the-geodesic-flo

Answer (score 0):

The [MathOverflow version of this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/88624/55893) has been answered there.
There are indeed coordinate free proofs of the fact as the answers there demonstrate.

If someone prefers to have a more detailed answer here, feel free to summarize the MO answers.
I just wanted to give this brief CW answer to help people find the answers and to remove this question from the unanswered list.